# React js, limiting post shown

Tags: reactjs, next.js, graphcms

Hi i am just making a blog using next js and graph cms,i just know how to limit the number posts shown, for example if i have 50 posts in the backend i just need 1 post to show, like how to limit it?

here, this is what i am talking about

```
const posts = [
    {title: 'Sample Post 1', description: 'Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet'},
    {title: 'Sample Post 2', description: 'Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet'}
];

<div>
       {
        posts.map((posts, index) => (
          <div>
            <h1>{posts.title}</h1>
             <p>{posts.description}</p>
             
           </div>
        ))
       }
    </div>
```

if i run this all the post will be show, is there anyway to limit in JS?

Comment: it depends if you want to slice them from the backend or frontend

Comment: First time working in a project like this i have no idea just gonna learn on the way

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you can use `slice`

```
{
   posts.slice(0,1).map((post, index) => (
     <div>
        <h1>{post.title}</h1>
        <p>{post.description}</p>       
     </div>
     ))
}
```

Comment: I am a javascript newbie thanks for helping me out <3

Comment: no problem. anytime.

Answer (score 2):

You can use [`.slice(0, 1)`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/slice).

Example:

```
export default function Posts() {
  const posts = [
    { title: "Sample Post 1", description: "Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet" },
    { title: "Sample Post 2", description: "Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet" },
    { title: "Sample Post 2", description: "Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet" },
    { title: "Sample Post 2", description: "Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet" },
    { title: "Sample Post 2", description: "Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet" },
    { title: "Sample Post 2", description: "Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet" },
  ];
  return (
    <div>
      {posts.slice(0, 1).map((posts, index) => (
        <div key={index}>
          <h1>{posts.title}</h1>
          <p>{posts.description}</p>
        </div>
      ))}
    </div>
  );
}
```

Comment: Thanks you so much for spending your time for helping me <3